# How exactly can I deal with validating form input in Spring when I need to use floats/doubles?

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm trying to get my head around Spring Boot and so I'm working on a small probability calculator app. My application needs to use doubles or floats for its calculations and it seems like Spring does not have an easy way of validating these data types. Now, it seems that I could change the `double` variables into `BigDecimal`, I tried that, but then I ran into another issue because I am working with logarithms and it quickly became apparent that doing any kind of calculation with `BigDecimal` is going to lead to big chunks of unnecessary code.

Is there really no easy way to validate Doubles and Floats?

Comment: Please explain in more detail what your "validation" consists of. (Note that in many common cases, such as dealing with money, you shouldn't be using floating-point anyway and something like JSR 354 Money is going to end up looking a lot like `BigDecimal`.)

Comment: @chrylis -cautiouslyoptimistic- I really only need to validate that the values are in between a certain range. If it's of any use, it's an app to estimate how much money you would have to spend in a Gacha game to get the item you want. You input the items drop chance as a probability from 0-1 and it then tells you how many times you'd have to 'roll the dice' so that the probability of obtaining the item at least once is close to 100%. The double for the money is just to get a conversion rate from $ to x amount of the in-game currency so that it can then show how much it may potentially cost.

Comment: any financial calculation use BigDecimal!

Comment: `@Min` and `@Max` are limited to integral bounds but do work with floating-point values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to validate the decimal numbers then you can use the following code

```
@DecimalMin(value = "0.1", inclusive = true)
@DecimalMax(value = "9.9", inclusive = true)
private BigDecimal measurement;
```